# Appsflyer Android onConversionDataSuccess not triggered when installing using Deferred Link

Tags: android, deep-linking, appsflyer

My project uses AppsFlyer's Deferred Link, which will capture af_dp as the basis for opening DeepLink after installation in the Play Store.

Test Deferred Link works during development (refer to official documentation),
But when the app is put on the Play Store, onConversionDataSuccess does not receive any parameters after opening the app for the first time after installation.

Everything works fine when testing, I don't know what's wrong

**Appsflyer SDK version:：5.1.0**

**onAppOpenAttribution:**

```
 {install_time=2022-04-25 10:22:19.584, af_status=Organic, af_message=organic install, is_first_launch=true}
```

**Debug Message：**

```
AppsFlyer_5.1.0: ******* sendTrackingWithEvent: Launch

AppsFlyer_5.1.0: IMEI was not collected.

AppsFlyer_5.1.0: AppsFlyer: first launch date: 2022-04-25_102220+0000

AppsFlyer_5.1.0: Cannot verify existence of our InstanceID Listener Service in the manifest. Please refer to documentation.

AppsFlyer_5.1.0: didConfigureTokenRefreshService=false

AppsFlyer_5.1.0: No deep link detected

AppsFlyer_5.1.0: AppsFlyerLib.sendTrackingWithEvent

AppsFlyer_5.1.0: Install referrer is allowed
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Having the same issue. Any solution?